# Quasar inputs @Change @Update

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, quasar

```
 <q-input dense outlined class="ml-5" v-model="date" @update:model-value="dateHandler" :value="date" mask="date" :rules="['date']">
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
            <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
              <q-date v-model="date">
                <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
                </div>
              </q-date>
            </q-popup-proxy>
          </q-icon>
        </template>
      </q-input>
or
  <q-input dense outlined class="ml-5" v-model="date" @change-value="dateHandler" :value="date"      mask="date" :rules="['date']">
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
            <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
              <q-date v-model="date">
                <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
                </div>
              </q-date>
            </q-popup-proxy>
          </q-icon>
        </template>
      </q-input>
```

```
function dateHandler(data){
  console.log(data,'fewfew')
}
```

function dateHandler(data) not return the value of input?

i also try with @input the same result nothig it looks like that from vue 3 composition api

Comment: Your first `<q-input>` works perfectly fine in a [sandbox](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/xxmVqqZ?editors=1011).  Your second one does not, but `@change-value` is not an event listed in the [q-input API](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#qinput-api) so that's to be expected.